# Python returning that number input is incorrect, but it is correct

Tags: python, string, random, numbers

I've made a python program that chooses between a random number or letter, the user then tries to guess it, but when the program chooses a number, and the correctly guesses the exact number, it returns with that the number the user inputted is incorrect.

This is my code:

```
import math
import random
import string


count = 0
numberroll = random.randint(1,10)
stringroll = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

chooseroll = random.choice([numberroll, stringroll.lower()])

# print(chooseroll)

count = 0
if chooseroll == numberroll:
    usernumberguess = input("Your guess: ")
    if usernumberguess.isdigit():
        print("It is a number!")
        count += 1
    else:
        print("That is not a number...")
    if usernumberguess.isdigit() == numberroll:
        print("Correct number!")
        count += 2
    else:
        print("Better luck next time!")

if chooseroll == stringroll.lower():
    userstringguess = input("Your guess: ")
    if userstringguess.isalpha():
        print("It is a letter!")
        count += 1
    else:
        print("That is not a letter...")
    if userstringguess.lower() == stringroll.lower():
        print("Correct letter!")
        count += 2
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Better luck next time!")

# print(count)
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share more of your code? It's difficult to debug without being able to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `if usernumberguess.isdigit() == numberroll:` may be faulty: `isdigit()` returns True or False, and you check if it is the `numberroll`. You can put that check whether the guess is correct within the case when the gues is a digit. You also need to turn your input, which is a string, into an `int`.

```py
if chooseroll == numberroll:
    usernumberguess = input("Your guess: ")
    if usernumberguess.isdigit():
        print("It is a number!")
        usernumberguess = int(usernumberguess)
        count += 1
        if usernumberguess == numberroll:
            print("Correct number!")
            count += 2
        else:
            print("Better luck next time!")
    else:
        print("That is not a number...")
```

I'd add some more code for debugging purposes so you can see what goes wrong:

```py
import random
random.seed(0)
count = 0
numberroll = random.randint(0, 9)
print(f"the user has to guess: {numberroll}")

usernumberguess = input("your guess: ")
print(f"your guess is {usernumberguess}")

if usernumberguess.isdigit():
    print("your guess is a number")
    usernumberguess = int(usernumberguess)
    count += 1
    if usernumberguess == numberroll:
        print("your guess is correct")
        count += 2
    else:
        print("your guess is not correct")
else:
    print("your guess is not a number")
```